# Disabling auto flush on standard error (Java)

Tags: java, redirectstandardoutput

My standard error error and standard output are getting garbled and I want to be able to put "\n" newline characters into standard error bound output without it auto-flushing. Is this physically possible in Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so. The `PrintSteam` `System.err` does not appear to be modifiable and I do not see any way for `java.lang.System.setErr` to convey this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I think that OP's self-answer is incorrect.

The answer is correct that `System.err` is not *directly* modifiable, and that `PrintStream` doesn't offer a way to toggle the autoflush setting.

However, if you study the source code for `java.lang.System` you will notice that the default `err` stream is set to a `PrintStream` that is created with `autoFlush` set to `true`.  If you dig further you will see that this print stream wraps a `FileOutputStream` created for the `FileDescriptor.err` fd.

And `System.setErr` is provided for cases where you need to update the (`final`) `System.err` variable.

So, you *should* be able to do this:

```
   FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(FileDescriptor.err);
   BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
   String encoding = ...
   PrintStream myErr = new PrintStream(bos, false, encoding);
   System.setErr(myErr);
```

---

I am not saying that this is a good idea though.

<sup>It would even be possible to use reflection to break abstraction on the initial `PrintStream` in `System.err` and change the private `autoFlush` variable.  But that is **a bad idea** ... and I only mentioned it to point this out!</sup>